# Pattern to call same object in different namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, webforms

I'm creating a web forms project in c#.

One of the key requirements is to post out to an API, however there's not one but several API's available.

At present the `HttpClient` object is uniquely defined for each API in a different namespace, like below:

```
MyCo.Myapp.PostApi.Client1.ClientObject
MyCo.Myapp.PostApi.Client2.ClientObject
```

Aside from the `HttpClient`, the endpoint url and mediatypes are stored as well as a few other configuration objects.

The idea being that the namespace `Client1` or `Client2` is stored in a database, and can be used to retrieve the location of the correct API, to create the object.

None of the above is set in stone - it's in concept form - so I wondered if there are any other alternatives to this solution which I can consider.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do the APIs correspond to a particular .NET Architecture or bitness?

Comment: Why would you use different objects, instead of a single object with a different configuration (the configuration would be stored in the db)?

Comment: @ParrishHusband - they're all third party API's that I have no control over, but all are accessed using an HttpClient. As an example, content could be url-encoded or json - there may be unique authorisation strings and different headers used.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I did contemplate putting the configuration in the database but it tends to be unique for each API. The worry was creating an unending mish-mash of variables in the db that would result in more complex code, and difficult to change if needs changed.

Comment: Note that if you're running ASP.NET Core 2.1 or above, you can use [`IHttpClientFactory` to create your `HttpClient` instances according to whatever criteria you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2)...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - good spot - using framework, but I think code is available via nuget. Will take a look.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read close enough; you're using Web Forms, so my comment may make less sense than it could...

Comment: @HereticMonkey - installed, taking a look

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a potential candidate for an [Abstract Factory](https://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) approach.  What you're describing sounds familiar to how one would connect to various database types using `System.Data.Common`

```
var settings = GetInfoFromDatabase();
var factory = ClientObjectFactory.Create(settings);

var clientObject = factory.CreateClientObject();
clientObject.Post("");  // This could be any of the client objects.
```

However since you don't have control over client APIs you could have the underlying factory perform the post:

```
factory.Post(clientObject, data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Parrish, I'm investigating.